# Connect call failed while connecting to PostreSQL inside docker container (aiohttp)

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, aiohttp

I've got a simple REST API which is using aiohttp, sqlalchemy and PostgreSQL.

I used to run my app locally and postgresql inside docker container. I connected to it using `localhost:5432`

Now I'm trying to add my app to docker-compose and I'm having problem with connecting to postgresql from it.

Here's my compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "listen_addresses=*"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: library
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass

  innerio:
    container_name: innerio
    restart: 'on-failure'
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/innerio
    command: python3 api/models.py && python3 main.py
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

My aiohttp running part:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    app = loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
    run_app(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

And the string which holds information about database:

```
DB_ADDRESS = 'postgresql://admin:pass@db:5432/library'
```

Using the above setup, I get this error:

> innerio    |     raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
>
> innerio    | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed
>   ('172.22.0.2', 5432)

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that your application is trying to connect to the database before postgres is actually listening.  You've set a `depends_on` key in your compose file, but that does almost nothing: it means that your application won't start until your postgres container has started, but that doesn't have anything to do with whether or not postgres is actually ready to service requests.

Ideally, you would write your application such that it is robust in the face of database connection failures. This would not only solve the startup problem, but also permits you to restart the database container while your application is active.

The simplest solution -- one that only solves the startup problem -- is to put your database connection in a loop, something like:

```
while True:
  try:
    connect_to_database()
    break
  except ConnectionRefusedError:
    log_error('database connection refused, retrying in 5 seconds...')
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while connecting to RabbitMQ from my Python script. An alternative would be to execute a shell script within `command` of your service, something like:

```
command: sh your.script.sh
```

In it you would use `netcat` to check if a proper connection with db has been established, like:

```
#!/bin/sh

## Repeat command until port 5432 on address db is not ready.
until nc -z -v -w30 db 5432
do
echo "Waiting for database connection for 5 seconds..."

## Wait for 5 seconds before check again.
sleep 5
done
echo "Database server ready..."

#### run your server afterwards
```

After this is completed successfully, you may execute the command for starting your server.